# How to make a Comment reply System using asp.net.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to show a post on a div and under that a reply of that post and consecutively want to show another posts and replies...
I did this much but that doesn't shows that desired output

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int i = 0;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=LOD-PC;uid=sa;pwd=1234;database=db2");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from t3 ORDER by id DESC", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                i++;
                string name = dr["name"].ToString();
                string image1 = dr["img"].ToString();
                string image2 = image1.Substring(2).ToString();
                string id = dr["id"].ToString();
                string status = dr["status"].ToString();
                string buttonid = i.ToString();

                Response.Write("<div id='myDiv' class='myDivClass'> <img src='" + image2 + "' style='width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin-right:6px;' /> <br/> <br/> <span class='name'> <input id='texta' class='texta' type='text' value=" + name.ToString() + " /> <span/> <span class='id'> <input id='textb' class='textb' type='text' value=" + id.ToString() + " /> <span/> <div id='g'><br/><br/><br/><span class='status'> " + status + " </span> <span class='combutton'> <input id='"+buttonid+"'  class='button' type='button' value='Comment'/> </span> </div> </div>");
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: **and also when I use Response.Write("any asp tag");** that doesn't shows in the page

Comment: You will get better help if you don't make us guess what it *does* show, and what is wrong with the output.

Comment: As a general rule, **don't use `Response.Write()` in a `Page`**. Use a web control instead.

Answer (score 0):

When outputting HTML based on your SQL query you are not quoting the text for the value:

```
value=" + id.ToString() + " />
```

That should be

value='" + id.ToString() + "' />

Other than that, you would have to provide more information about what is not appearing as you expect it should.  However, I can address the following points:

> Response.Write("any asp tag")

ASP tags are processed server-side, not client side.  Writing them to the response will not cause them to be executed.  If you "view source" on your HTML in the browser, you would see the tags in the HTML source, but they don't mean anything special to the browser.

Please dispose of things that implement IDisposable such as SqlConnection, SqlCommand, and SqlDataReader.  The *using* keyword is the way to go there.  For example with

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=LOD-PC;uid=sa;pwd=1234;database=db2");
```

The line

```
con.Close();
```

will not be executed if an exception is thrown accessing the database.

Instead, use the form

```
using (SqlConnection con = 
     new SqlConnection("server=LOD-PC;uid=sa;pwd=1234;database=db2"))
{
    // Do stuff with the connection
}
```

When the *using* block goes out of scope, it will call `con.Dispose()` automatically (whether or not an exception was thrown within the block), which in turn will call `con.Close()`.

> server=LOD-PC;uid=sa

Please do not connect with the `sa` user.  That is asking for security breeches.